# UITableview Display Blank Cell When It Have Multiple Custom Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, collectionview

I have `UITableView` with three custom `cells`. One of my cell has `UICollectionView` inside. Based on my condition all `UITableViewCells` are a shuffle. my problem is when I scrolling up my `UITableView` and scrolling down that again its display blank cell. I don't know how my reusable `TableViewCell` is work.

Comment: Well you have said it yourself. You don't know how cell reuse works. Read up on it. There are tons of resources out there. Then try something. Show us what you have tried and the explain the problem you are facing and then we might be of help to you.

Comment: Even we can use multiple cells having collection view in each cell along with other custom cells.  Please explain your issue , will help you out with simple the code. Thanks

Comment: Kindly add code snippets or what your current setup is so we could help faster.